# XSLT - Combine multiple attributes (concatenate) after flattening the xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xml that I'm flattening (elements to attributes)

input xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<queryResponse type="Clients" rootUrl="https://10.130.0.192/webacs/api/v1/data" requestUrl="https://10.30.0.192/webacs/api/v1/data/Clients?.full=true&amp;.firstResult=0&amp;.maxResults=1000" responseType="listEntityInstances" count="349" first="0" last="348">
  <entity url="https://10.130.0.192/webacs/api/v1/data/Clients/621621" type="Clients" dtoType="clientsDTO">
    <clientsDTO id="621621" displayName="621621">
      <associationTime>1474746255456</associationTime>
      <clientInterface>GigabitEthernet1/0/16</clientInterface>
      <connectionType>WIRED</connectionType>
      <deviceIpAddress>10.1.1.254</deviceIpAddress>
      <deviceName>stack</deviceName>
      <deviceType>Unknown</deviceType>
      <ipAddress>10.30.0.106</ipAddress>
      <location>Unknown</location>
      <macAddress>macaddress</macAddress>
      <protocol>DOT3</protocol>
      <securityPolicyStatus>PASSED</securityPolicyStatus>
      <status>ASSOCIATED</status>
      <updateTime>1474746256758</updateTime>
      <vendor>Netapp</vendor>
      <vlan>vlan_300_server</vlan>
      <vlanId>300</vlanId>
    </clientsDTO>
  </entity>
 </queryResponse>
```

xslt:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="queryResponse">
    <Data>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="clientsDTO">
    <Client>
      <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </Client>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which works fine and provides me with my flattened output xml.

Now with this XSLT I'd like to add one more thing.
The elements clientInterface and deviceName would need to be (additionaly) concatenated as a new attribute.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Update:

My current output xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
   <Client associationTime="1474746255456" clientInterface="GigabitEthernet1/0/16" connectionType="WIRED" deviceIpAddress="10.1.1.254" deviceName="stack" deviceType="Unknown" ipAddress="10.130.0.106" location="Unknown" macAddress="macaddress" protocol="DOT3" securityPolicyStatus="PASSED" status="ASSOCIATED" updateTime="1474746256758" vendor="Netapp" vlan="vlan_300_server" vlanId="300" />
</Data>
```

Now within that one " I would like to have a new attribute which concatenates the deviceName and clientInterface resulting in:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
   <Client **deviceId="stack_GigabitEthernet1/0/16"**associationTime="1474746255456" clientInterface="GigabitEthernet1/0/16" connectionType="WIRED" deviceIpAddress="10.1.1.254" deviceName="stack" deviceType="Unknown" ipAddress="10.130.0.106" location="Unknown" macAddress="macaddress" protocol="DOT3" securityPolicyStatus="PASSED" status="ASSOCIATED" updateTime="1474746256758" vendor="Netapp" vlan="vlan_300_server" vlanId="300" />
</Data>
```

Comment: May be you can add the desired ouput xml as well in your question for better clarity.

Comment: Added in what I got so far and what I would like to achieve. the new element is in ** and called deviceId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
<xsl:template match="clientsDTO">
    <Client>
        <xsl:attribute name="deviceId">
            <xsl:value-of select="deviceName"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="clientInterface"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[not(*)]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Client>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Note**: using the `descendant` axis is inefficient - and unnecessary in your case.

Comment: Perfect! Seems to do exactly what I want. The descendant was indeed still a leftover from a previous transformation (where it did make sense) but can be removed here.